# Role of the observer in Gödel's universe

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, metric-tensor, observers, closed-timelike-curve

I am here to clarify myself about the role of the observer in Gödel's solution (1949) of Einstein's field equations.

The Universe we are dealing with is **anisotropic**, since the axis of rotation defines a directional preference, while still **homogeneous**, as every observer is equivalent. The last fact is driving me crazy, as it always does when I have to deal with some formulation of the **cosmological principle**. In this particular case, though, things get even weirder and harder to grasp.

Every observer can perceive the whole Universe (modelled as a uniform distribution of dust) rotating around himself, since the homogeneity of the solution allows us to fix the axis of rotation wherever we want, not altering its direction.

[image: Light-cones tilting in Gödel's Universe, as perceived by an observer fixed along the axis of rotation]

As shown in the previous picture, once we have **chosen** (and here's the big deal) a position for the observer, we have that its **light-cone** is aligned with the axis of rotation, while the **light-cones** surrounding him start **tilting** until they reach a **critical radius**, where they intersect spatial base vectors and allow **closed time-like curves (CTCs)** to exist. As an observer, I can *easily* (whatever that means in this context) perceive a rocket which travels along one of those **CTCs**, since I see his light-cones tilted.

[image: CTC]

My doubts precisely regard what happens If we swap the roles of the **observer** and the **observed**. Consider the rocket as the new observer and the "central" observer as the new observed. Since the solution provides us a homogeneous Universe, we **must** consider the axis of rotation **fixed on the rocket's position at any given spacetime point it gets to**. Well, that's quite a problem. Having the axis fixed at its position, the rocket always perceives its light-cone as **non-tilted**, while the central observer's one gets more and more tilted as the rocket gets far from him. The point is the following: if this universe is homogeneous, thus we can consider every point of it as its center of rotation, how can a body go through a CTC? Does the rocket go through the CTC **just in the reference frame of the central observer**? How can I figure the situation from a physical point of view without **contradicting myself**? Can, **anyhow**, an observer **find himself** going through a closed time-like curve? Does the homogeneity prevent this?